# Refresh only the partial view on submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a main page (Index.cshtml) that contains several divs.

The divs contains Ignite UI Grids and their Editors.

```
<div id="grid">           
    <p>
        <a id='openDialog' href='Home/ManageContact?cntID=0&command=create' class='openDialog ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only' style="color: black;">ADD CONTACT
            @*<button>ADD CONTACT</button>*@</a>
    </p>
    <span><table id="contactGrid" style="width: auto;"></table></span>
</div>
```

I have the editor of this grid in a separate partial view with a `Html.BeginForm` form. I put the Grid in another separate view. What I want to do is, when I click on submit in the Editor partial view only this Grid will be refreshed and not the whole Index page. My Update function is redirecting to `Index()` method, I tried to redirect it to the `GridPartialView()` but it didn't work. It loads the grid in another page.

Can you please tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to use ajax to submit the data, and replace the content of the div using javascript.

Comment: Or just Ajax.BeginForm, where you can specify the UpdateTargetId

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I don't really know how to use ajax in this case. Is there any example that I can follow ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try your best to separate the inline css into a separate css file to make the coding clearer

Anyway, here is the sample code should help you start

```
<script>
    $(".btn-class').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'your controller action",
            data: data,
            type:'POST/GET',
            success:function(html){
                $('#grid').html(html);
            }
            error:function(error){
                //things you want to do
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it s helpful, with minor modifications i made it work thank you. I also took your advice regarding the CSS files. Thank you